# Meteor LESS recompile?

Tags: meteor, less

I'm trying to troubleshoot a LESS issue with my Meteor code..

I have bootstrap3-less package installed but I don't know where Meteor is getting it's LESS files from. This whole time I thought it was coming from a .less file in my client/ folder but I removed that entirely but for some reason my Meteor CSS file does not change once I remove that. But yet, when I inspect the compiled CSS file, it stayed exactly the same.

However, when I make changes to my .css file Meteor picks that up right away..

Anyone have this experience? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `bootstrap3-less` package contains the less code inside itself. If you want to use your own less code instead of the code inside `bootstrap3-less`, you should `remove bootstrap3-less`.

Here you can see the code that the `bootstrap3-less` package adds to your app: https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less

They suggest that you can customize bootstrap by adding the less file to your client folder, but even if you don't have that file the app will load all of the less content from the package.

Comment: does the main Meteor CSS file get cached? Because I swear I've deleted some LESS files but that CSS file contains stuff that only be from those LESS files... e.g. I had some Font Awesome LESS files but I got rid of all them but the main compiled CSS file still has FA references...

Comment: Have you considered that the font awesome stuff could be coming from one of your packages?